# Hiding the Navigation Pane cause a problem when exiting the database

Tags: ms-access

I just found something strange with MS-Access 2016. I have a database with 2 forms: one hidden, one for a menu. The autoexec will open the hidden form and that one will open the menu form.

I unchecked some options, under Current Database e.g. [Display Navigation Pane] and [Allow Full Menus].

I have an exit button/command on the menu form. On Click, it calls DoCmd.Quit. But before exiting, I am getting an MS-Access window asking for the parameter that is normally when the form open, not when it is closing.

After doing a lot of testing and I mean a lot, I realised that the problem is related to the fact that I am disabling the [Display Navigation Pane]. If I keep the navigation pane, but instead I unchecked all Object Type, then everything works correctly.

So, my question is why disabling the navigation pane can create something like that and is there a way to fix it?

Yes, my solution works, but I don’t like it since users can open and close the navigation pane using the shutter bar; nothing shows but it is still distracting and users can call for support.

The problem is not related to the fact that the first form is hidden, but because it is open. If I add a DoCmd.Close acForm, “F_Parameter” before my DoCmd.Quit then it works.

It is easy to reproduce the problem:

Create a new database

Create two forms:
F_Parameter
F_Menu

Create a Macro named Autoexec:
OpenForm
Form Name: F_Parameter
Window Mode: Hidden

In form F_Parameter create an event On Load

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  DoCmd.OpenForm “F_Menu”
End Sub
```

In form F_Menu create a Button named Btn_Exit with an event On Click

```
Private Sub Btn_Exit_Click()
  DoCmd.Quit
End Sub
```

In form F_Menu create an event On Load

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  MsgBox “Hello”
End Sub
```

go File, Options, Current Database and
uncheck Display Navigation Pane and
uncheck Allow Full Menus

Save, exit and open the database:
You will get a “Hello” because the F_Menu form open, now click on the exit and you will get another “Hello”. This second one should not be there because the form should be closing not opening.

Comment: This question is not reproducible as presented - I doubt anyone will want to build this setup to test, I don't. Unless someone else has also experienced this exact same issue, you may be SOL here. You might post to a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

Comment: I added how to reproduce the problem. Took me more time to write it down then to do it in Access. 10 min max. Hope someone will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue described. I don't think it has anything to do with the Navigation Pane.

This is happening because while the `DoCmd.Quit` event is occurring, the hidden F_Parameter form is becoming "unhidden" in order for Access to close it. This causes the F_Parameter `Form.Load` event to run, which is essentially opening F_Menu, thus causing the `Form.Load` event on F_Menu to run.

I was able to solve this by first explicitly closing F_Parameter, then quitting:

`DoCmd.Close ObjectType:=acForm, ObjectName:="F_Parameter", Save:=acSaveNo`

`DoCmd.Quit`

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for trying it; I really appreciate that.